# Reload App upon AUTH_LOGOUT or AUTH_ERROR

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there a good way to reload the entire application upon (type === AUTH_LOGOUT) and make sure it completes reloading before we representing the Login page?

Thanks!

Comment: `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: I tried that but it did not have a way to ensure the app is fully reloaded (no callback for window.location.reload())

Comment: You don't need to ensure? That is what reload does. And by the nature of it, this function can't have callback(It is a bit like reopening browser).

Answer (score 1):

Which version of admin-on-rest are you using? There was a bug prior to v1.1.0, now the state resets after a logout, and the whole app should rerender.